# VSCode Intellisense does not display methods on prototype with 'method' type

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: Using prototype]
[image: Using class]

Why didn't vscode show methods on prototype with type 'method' ? As the following is absolutely impossible in JavaScript:

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 'bar'
}

function Foo.prototype.getBar () {
  return this.bar
}
```

Or how can I get the same annotation with the 'class' sample ?

Answer (score 0):

While this seems to be a VSCode limitation at the moment, Intellisense does seem to find the prototype methods of classes.

Intellisense in module implementation (FooBar.js):
[image]
Intellisense in module import location (Main.js):
[image]

Creating static members works as expected using the 'static' keyword.